# ionic ngform submit on presenting modal

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, angularjs-ng-form

I have created a form, in the form I have a button

```
<form #f='ngForm' (ngSubmit)='onAddBusiness(f)' >
....
....
    <ion-item>

            <button ion-button icon-left outline block (click)='openMap()'>
              بۆ دیاریکردنی شوێن کلیک لێرە بکە
              <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <p *ngIf="(position==undefined); else elseblock">
              هیچ شوێنێک دیاری نەکراوە
            </p>

            <ng-template #elseblock>
              <p #elseblock>
                دەست خۆش شوێنەکە دیاری کرا
              </p>
            </ng-template>

          </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
        <button type='submit'   ion-button block [disabled]="!f.valid">ناردن</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
```

the button is present a Modal to set the location on a map.
The issue is  whenever I click the Button to open the modal, the form is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the button to open modal, specify the `type` as `button`.

```
<button type='button' ion-button icon-left outline block (click)='openMap()'>
    بۆ دیاریکردنی شوێن کلیک لێرە بکە
    <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Can you upvote, it will help people to know this answer works